# Averages of table with numeric and non numeric data (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, numeric

Hi I'm fairly new to coding (Matlab) and was wondering if anyone knew how to do this. I have a table with numeric data with some non numeric data throughout it. I want to go through the table data and find the average of each row in my table excluding the non numeric figures.
Thanks

This is the table:

```
|    a     |     b    |    c     |     d     |
|----------|----------|----------|-----------|
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '71.725'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | 'xxxxx'  | '82.778'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '84.265'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '38.964'  |
| '2.258'  | '0.000'  | '1.628'  | '6.646'   |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '1.245'  | '129.554' |
| '0.000'  | ''       | '0.000'  | '63.066'  |
| '0.000'  | ''       | '0.303'  | '84.729'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '-0.001' | '114.079' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.182'  | '20.956'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | 'xxxxx'  | '15.421'  |
| '0.000'  | ''       | 'ygvt'   | '57.726'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | 'ijuhyg' | '85.433'  |
| '0.000'  | ''       | '0.000'  | '106.965' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.294'  | '132.627' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | 'abc'    | '46.133'  |
| '12.864' | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '1.850'   |
| '42.991' | 'aaaa'   | '14.562' | '47.279'  |
| '49.822' | 'bbbb'   | '17.713' | '65.436'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '85.881'  |
| '29.429' | '0.000'  | '1.322'  | '29.684'  |
| '11.784' | 'cccc'   | '0.000'  | '73.187'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '110.376' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '66.343'  |
| '0.886'  | '0.000'  | '0.588'  | '38.150'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '24.694'  |
| '23.437' | '22.697' | '0.000'  | '9.468'   |
| '34.642' | '35.602' | '13.136' | '47.170'  |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '120.737' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '196.755' |
| '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '0.000'  | '176.882' |
```

Comment: Adding an MWE is always helpful to get help from this site. If you add what you have done to accomplish the task, then others can help you. So, please add any code that you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all the data in the table is currently strings. Some of those strings *look* like numbers and can be parsed to them, but they're not actually numeric.

Parse those strings using `str2double` to convert them to numerics. The strings that look like numbers will turn in to number values. The strings that don't look like numbers will turn in to `NaN` values. Then use `nanmean()` to get the average, ignoring NaNs.

```
>> strs = {'1.234', 'whatever', '23.483', 'banana'}
strs =
  1×4 cell array
    {'1.234'}    {'whatever'}    {'23.483'}    {'banana'}
>> x = str2double(strs)
x =
    1.2340       NaN   23.4830       NaN
>> nanmean(x)
ans =
   12.3585
>>
```